# Finding anagram with repeated letters in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to find anagram in bash.

I tried following code, it suppose give me the result "steep", but it is not working.

```
grep -P '^(?:([eepst])(?!.*?\1)){5}$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Btw, this is a question of school assignment. There is a tip says that 'cut' might be useful.

Comment: you might have a look at this, ['an' - very fast anagram generator](http://fatphil.org/words/an.html)

Comment: Your not gonna be able to find anagrams with a single regex.

Comment: Don't confuse `bash` with commands run from `bash`.

Comment: Your solution does work for words with no repeating characters though. The problem is that `\1` disallows all character repetition even if one would be allowed in an anagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this example :

```
$ cat /usr/share/dict/words
step
steep
stop
```

These commands will behave like :

```
# grep all combinations of the letters in bracket on line with exactly 5 chars
$ grep -Ei  "^[epst]{5}$" /usr/share/dict/words
steep

# grep all combinations of the letters in bracket on line with exactly 4 chars
$grep -Ei "^[epst]{4}$" /usr/share/dict/words
step

# grep all combination of the letters in bracket on line with exactly 4 chars
$grep -Ei "^[opst]{4}$" /usr/share/dict/words
stop

# grep all combinations of the letters in bracket on line with exactly 4 chars
$grep -Ei "^[eopst]{4}$" /usr/share/dict/words
step
stop

# grep all combinations of the letters in bracket on line with exactly 1 to 5 chars
$grep -Ei "^[epst]{1,5}$" /usr/share/dict/words
step
steep
```

If the file `/usr/share/dict/words` is not structured as one word per line, and more of a :

```
steep|rising or falling sharply; almost perpendicular.
```

This could be why the `cut` tip was mentioned

An implementation could be :

```
grep -Ei  "^[epst]{,5}\|" /usr/share/dict/words | cut -d'|' -f1
```

Comment: this doesn't consider the case the characters repeats? say "ssss" or "stoo"

Comment: @Crystina yes it does, the regular expression will match any combination of the letters in brackets, that is why a word like steep is matched, try adding "ssss" in the file dictionnary to test it

Comment: yes "ssss" will be matched, but the anagram of `epst` shouldn't include "ssss"?

Comment: @Crystina Oh, sorry, didn't understand the question this way. Sure it doesn't take into account this kind of word. I give the simplest answer considering that the question implied a dictionary input. You would need a more complex algorythm to achieve that